# Display fetched data from api

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I have fetched data from API and I am trying to display them as an array. 
I was able to log request the data and log them into the console.

[image]

I was unable to display them into the array.

This is my service component:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EarthquakeService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getEarthquakes(){
    return this.http.get('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson');
  }


}
```

This is my app component where I am requesting the data:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {EarthquakeService} from '../../services/earthquake/earthquake.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-earthquake-page',
  templateUrl: './earthquake-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./earthquake-page.component.scss']
})
export class EarthquakePageComponent implements OnInit {

  earthquakes: string[];
  eathqaukeTitle: string;

  constructor(private earthquakeService: EarthquakeService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEarthqaukes();


  }

  getEarthqaukes(){
    this.earthquakeService.getEarthquakes().subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }

}
```

Now I am not sure how to save those data into an array and display them on the page.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: You should probably go to https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 and work your way through the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing some parts when making your `http` request to get data try something like the following. The request should look similar to what follows, cant work out the JSON very well from picture.

**Request**

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


public getEarthquakes(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/
      earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson').pipe(map(data => data));
}

//only on two lines for SO readability
```

**Component**

```
 public earthQuakes = [];    

  getEarthqaukes(){
  this.earthquakeService.getEarthquakes().subscribe(
    (response) => {
       console.log(response)
       this.earthQuakes = response.features; // whichever bit you are looking for.
  },
  (error) => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let shake of earthQuakes">
  <span>{{shake}}</span>
</div>
```

[Documentation on using *ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data).

This is not perfect as mentioned cant see full JSON well, but this should definitely be enough to fill in the gaps. As mentioned in the comments by [the head rush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3812888/the-head-rush) you should look through this [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt60) to make sure you understand what you are doing as you learn.